# Quarkus keycloak config not workin. quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.enable=true not working in .yaml representation

Tags: java, yaml, keycloak, quarkus

I am using the io.quarkus:quarkus-keycloak-authorization quarkus extension and want to use the `AuthzClient`. The [official documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-keycloak-authorization#injecting-the-authorization-client) tells us that one must set the configuration parameter `quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.enable` to `true`.
If one uses an `application.properties` file this works like a charm.
But if I change to a `application.yaml` the setting is not recognized anymore.

`application.properties`:

```
quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.enable=true
quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.paths.default.path=/public/*
quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.paths.default.enforcement-mode=DISABLED
```

`application.yaml`

```yaml
quarkus:
    keycloak:
        policy-enforcer:
            enable: true
                paths:
                    default:
                        path: /public/*
                        enforcement-mode: disabled
```

How can I set up the `application.yaml` to work like my `application.properties` config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution was very straightforwar. Other than Spring Boot, Quarkus does not support YAML configuration files out of the box so you need to add the extension `quarkus-config-yaml`.

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-config-yaml</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

build.gradle.kts:

```
implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-config-yaml")
```